# Tensorflow to Pytorch CNN(Use nn.Conv1d)

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, conv-neural-network, conv1d

```
input_size = [765, 500, 72]

model = Sequential()
add = model.add

add(l.Conv1D(256, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu')
add(l.Dropout(0.5))
add(l.Conv1D(256, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu')
add(l.Dropout(0.5))
add(l.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
add(l.Dense(100, activation="relu"))
add(l.Dense(3, activation="softmax"))


(None, 249, 256)
(None, 249, 256)
(None, 124, 256)
(None, 124, 256)
(None, 256)
(None, 100)
(None, 3)
```

This is tensorflow model struc and summary.
Tensorflow to Pytorch CNN model.
Use Conv1D

[Tensorflow Model summary]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To jump-start your research, here is an example usage of [`nn.Conv1d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html):

```
>>> f = nn.Conv1d(72, 256, kernel_size=3, stride=2)
>>> f(torch.rand(765, 72, 500)).shape
torch.Size([765, 256, 249])
```

Regarding this case keep in mind a few PyTorch-related things :

- Unlike Tensorflow, it handles data in the `BHC` format.
- You have to provide the input feature sizes for each linear layer.
- The activation function is not included in `nn.Conv1d`, you have to use a dedicated module for that (*eg.* [`nn.ReLU`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ReLU.html)).

Comment: Thanks!

I modified the tensorflow code to pytorch.

Comment: ```
input_shape = [765, 500, 72]
conv1d_1 = nn.Conv1d(72, 256, stride=2, kernel_size=3)
conv1d_2 = nn.Conv1d(249, 256, stride=2, kernel_size=3)
relu = nn.ReLU()
softmax = nn.Softmax()
dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)
dense_1 = nn.Linear(256, 100)
dense_2 = nn.Linear(100, 3)


out = input.transpose(1, 2)
out = relu(conv1d_1(out)).transpose(1, 2)
out = dropout(out)
out = relu(conv1d_2(out)).transpose(1, 2)
out = dropout(out)
out = out[:, -1, :]
out = relu(dense_1(out))
out = softmax(dense_2(out))
```

Comment: but, It showed a different structure from the tensorflow model summary.
When the conv1d_2 model proceeds, the size was output as [765, 127, 256] instead of [765, 124, 256].
Can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question with the updated logs.

Comment: Adds a TensorFlow summary image!